# Sum of roots of unity an algebraic integer proof

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let S be the sum of a finite number of nth roots of unity (where n is fixed, and the sum is non-zero). How do I go about showing that S is an algebraic integer in the cyclotomic field of order n ?

Comment: The short answer is that the algebraic integers form a ring, but closed under addition is the hard part of that proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K= \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.  We have
$$(\zeta^{a} + \zeta^{b})\zeta^{c} = \zeta^{c+a} + \zeta^{c+b},$$
so we can form a matrix of the action of $\zeta^{a} + \zeta^{b}$ on the basis $\{\zeta^{i}\}_{i = 0}^{n - 2}$ (since $(\zeta^{a} + \zeta^{b})\mathbb{Z}[\zeta] \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is a finitely generated additive subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$).  The characteristic polynomial then shows that $\zeta^{a} + \zeta^{b}$ is an algebraic integer.

Say $n = 7$ and $a = 2, b = 3$.  Then $\zeta^{2} + \zeta^{3}$ acts on $\{\zeta^{i}\}$ as
$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
For example, the fourth row comes from
$$(\zeta^{2} + \zeta^{3})\zeta^{3} = \zeta^{5} + \zeta^{6} = \zeta^{5} + \sum_{i = 0}^{5} -\zeta^{i}.$$
This gives us the equation
$$(\zeta^{2} + \zeta^{3})\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\zeta\\
\zeta^{2}\\
\zeta^{3}\\
\zeta^{4}\\
\zeta^{5}
\end{bmatrix} = M\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\zeta\\
\zeta^{2}\\
\zeta^{3}\\
\zeta^{4}\\
\zeta^{5}
\end{bmatrix}.$$
But this says that $\zeta^{2} + \zeta^{3}$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, so is a zero of its characteristic polynomial $\text{det}(xI - M)$.